# Create semi transparent uibutton with solid white text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I am trying to create button similar to following:
[image]

I have tried to give alpha with white text color but I am getting following:

[image]

**Edit:**

```
textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0.7, blue: 0.7, alpha: 0.7)
textfield.textColor = .white
```

Above code gives second image. But above image looks ugly.

How can I create uitextfield like first image?

**Edit:**
Complete Solution:

```
txtLogin.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.1)
    txtLogin.textColor = .white
    txtLogin.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Username",
                                                      attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 241, alpha: 0.7)])
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 20))
    txtLogin.leftView = paddingView
    txtLogin.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always

    let layer: CALayer! = txtLogin.layer
    layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    layer.borderWidth = 0
```

Regards

Comment: What did you do to make the image on the bottom? Post some code.

Comment: please check edit

Comment: So you're telling me that the code you tried doing was literally the exact same as the code I suggested?

Comment: I did it from storyboard earlier, but when I tried your code it gave same result

Comment: 1)1 way: I think you should create the uiview with image view inside(take the image from the first screen and set it to image view). Next add the uitextfiled for full view size with clear color background. Also set the placeholder for it with white color.
2) 2 way: need to play with corners, setup border, border color, play with bg it seems buttons bg got the "glossy effect", so you should use custom gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is set the alpha of the button to the point that you want. So for example this would have a semi-transparent background and white text color:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.1)
button.textColor = .white
button.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"placeholder text",
                                                   attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white])
```

Comment: it is giving similar image

Comment: @pankaj, is it a similar image or the same image? Why did you post my code as your own. What did you actually try?

Comment: I am sorry for posting it as my code, I meant I tried your code but it gave same result

Comment: @WMios why hit and try. Just give the background of textfield as white with alpha 0.1. `textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1)`

Comment: I tried this, now when I enter text it appears fine but the placeholder is still the same, Is it possible to change placeholder color to white also?

Comment: @pankaj, yes I added how to do that

Comment: Thanks WMios, In addition to above code I have added some padding in beginning, rounded corner, some translucence to placeholder and now it is almost similar to the first image.

Comment: yes did same, and have also posted complete code above in my question as edit